# How can I display my updated output in browser django

Tags: python, django, heroku, auto-update, apscheduler

Hello guys hope you are fine...
I want to ask something from you I really need help from you because I am stuck in this problem...
I deployed my (django) app in heroku and in that app I used apscheduler which works fine (which basically get historical weather data from api and then train my model on that data and gives me predictions ) and I shows that new prediction values on console but not in browser which I wants to every time when my scheduler runs and got new prediction values then those new values should be shown on my browser instead of old values. How can I achieve this task??
Thanks in advance....

Comment: look into websockets

Comment: standard method is to use `JavaScript` which runs in web browser and it asks server for new values every few seconds and it updates only these values in web browser. Older method was to use meta tag which reloads page every few seconds - but it reads full page from server and replaces all HTML in web browser. The newer method is to use `websockets` but it may need extra modules for this.

Comment: Can I use ajax instead of websockets ?